# How to redirect to target url after authenticated by wso2 identity server using saml sso?

Tags: wso2

I am studying wso2 and trying to configure the sso sample follow by this article
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0
In this article, it configured home.jsp as assertion consumer url, so when user access home.jsp, it will first go to identity server for authentication and then redirect back to home.jsp, this is fine. However, I realized if I have another jsp file, for example, new.jsp, if I hit new.jsp, it still redirects me to home.jsp.  So what should I do to redirect me to new.jsp?
I searched about previous posts, and someone mentioned about RelayState , so how should I set the target url to this RelayState? Any sample will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to redirect ACS(Assertion Consumer Service) to other url you have to do some customization in the authentication process. Basic authenticator is the default and local authenticator in WSO2 Identity Server. In this case after successfully authenticate, we have to invoke the custom implementation. Please look at this blog post[2] for write custom authenticator.

This extends from the Basic Authenticator.

1.Create a jar file by building as a maven project.

2.Put this jar file to dropins directory that located inside the /repository/components directory.

3.Edit the login.jsp with new custom authenticator name and that located 
/repository/deployments/server/webapps/uthenticationendpoint/login.jsp

4.Configure the application-authentication.xml that is located /repository/conf/security/application-authentication.xml.

AuthenticatorConfig name=" BasicCustomAuthenticator" and enabled="true"

5.Restart the server.
6.Log into the Management console and configure new authenticator for each service Provider under “Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration”. Select you customized authenticator from drop down list as the Local Authenticator. Then Update.

[1] http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/10/15/custom-authenticator-for-wso2-identity-server-wso2is-sso-login/

Comment: This answer is not correct.  You do not need to use custom authenticator to do it.  This can be handled at application not in the IDP level.   Application can use relaystate  value to keep the state of the jsp file which is access before authentication process is started.